# Ошибка в типе данных 'String' and 'System::String

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, получаю ошибку:

> [BCC32 Error] File1.cpp(40): E2015 Ambiguity between 'String' and 'System::String'

Код:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class String
{

private:
    char *str;
public:
    String();
    String(char *s);
    String(const String &);
    ~String();
     String& operator-=(const String& op);
    void input();
    void see();

};

String::String()
{
    strcpy(str,"");
}

String::String(char *s)
{
    strcpy(str,s);
}

String::String(const String &a)
{

    strcpy(str,a.str);
}

String::~String()
{
    if(str) delete [] str;
}
String & String::operator-=(const String & op)
   {
    int i;
    for(i=0;*(this->str)==op.str[i]&&*(this->str)&&op.str[i];i++){
        this->str++;
    }
    return *this;
}

void String::see()
{
    cout<<"new string: "<<str<<endl;
}

void String::input()
{
    cout << "Enter String: ";
    gets(str);
}

int main()
{
    String a,b;
    a.input();
    b.input();
    b-=a;
    b.see();

    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Укажите в коде, к какому конкретно типу обращаетесь. Например, указав полное имя типа вместе с пространствами имен.

Comment: Переименуйте свой тип, что бы он не совпадал с существующим. Либо заключите все в свой namespace.